# Getting documentation for older versions JDBC jars

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am using 9.3-1102-jdbc41 jar in my java application.

**1)** I want to know which versions of postgreSQL servers does it supports? I am unable to find the online documentation which describes it. Can some one share a link to such a documentation?

Regards

Comment: Check its release date. It will sopport all PostgreSQL versions with an older release date. But really, you should upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Look no further than https://jdbc.postgresql.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  [link for JDBC documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/) appears on first glance to just have the information about the latest JDBC version.

However, at the bottom of the page is a link which says '**see full changelog**'. By clicking on this link, the information for all the old versions (including 9.3-1102-jdbc41) can be viewed by scrolling down the page.